# Passing same props to child elements at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Since the original source code is too big. I can't post it, let me give you another short example.

Parent (ES6 class component)

```
render(){
    const { sortKey, isactive } = this.state;
    return (
        <Sort cKey={sortKey} title="A" name="Title" />
        <Sort cKey={sortKey} title="B" name="Author" />
        <Sort cKey={sortKey} title="C" name="Comment" />
        <Sort cKey={sortKey} title="D" name="Point" />
    )
}
```

For simplicity i wrote only 4 Sort components. As you can see all Sort components have the same cKey property. Does React have simple way to pass this property to all Sort components at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map of titles and names is actually needed:

```
titleNameMap = new Map([
  ['A', 'Title'],
  ...
]);
// or since `Map`-specific features aren't in use, `Map` could be skipped:
titleNameMap = [
  ['A', 'Title'],
  ...
];

render(){
    const { sortKey, isactive } = this.state;
    return (
        [...titleNameMap].map(([title, name]) => <Sort cKey={sortKey} title={title} name={name} />);
    )
}
```

> As you can see all Sort components have the same cKey property. Does React have simple way pass this property to all Sort components at once?

React is minimalistic and unopinionated, it doesn't address such cases. A recommended approach is to use higher-order components (HOC):

```
const withSortKey = (WrappedComponent, sortKey) => props => (
  <WrappedComponent cKey={sortKey} {...props} />
));

...
render(){
    const { sortKey, isactive } = this.state;
    const KeyedSort = withSortKey(Sort, sortKey);
    return (
        [...titleNameMap].map(([title, name]) => <KeyedSort title={title} name={name} />);
    )
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you @estus. HOC with dynamic props solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rendering the Sort components separately, you can simply render them using a map like

```
return (
    [{title: 'A', name: "Title"}, { title: 'B',  name: "Author"}, {title: 'C', name: "Comment"},{ title: 'D',  name: "Point"}].map((obj) => {
         return <Sort key={obj.title} cKey={sortKey} title={obj.title} name={obj.name}/>
    })

)
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I have more than 2 prop in the Sort elements?  <Sort cKey={sortKey} title="B" active={isActive} />. I updated the question.

Comment: If the same value needs to be passed on to the component, you can pass it directly to the mapped Component just like cKey, however if its different, you can convert Array into an Array of object and then render it

Comment: Ok Thanks again, would you mind update your answer with the current question?

Comment: Than you @Shubham Khatri,  but does React have simple way to do this?

Comment: React provides a Context way that you can use, but its not recommended to just use it for the purpose of passing props

Comment: `{title: 'A', name: "Title"}` definition is verbose but a good thing is that it allows to replace `title={obj.title} name={obj.name}` with `{...obj}`.

Comment: @estus, yes we can do that too